# How do I rotate an NSTextField on OS X?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa

Does OS X have an  equivalent of `[UIView setTransform:]` on iOS? I have an `NSTextField` that I want to rotate 10 degrees. In iOS I’d just use `[UILabel setTransform:]`. Is there anything equivalent for Cocoa Framework?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`frameRotation` or `frameCenterRotation` should do that

Comment: Wow, that easy? I was thinking about transforms didn't even notice there was a simple solution like that!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the underlying layer and rotate that

```
myView.wantsLayer = YES;
myView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0, 1);
```

p.s. 
Remember to import QuartzCore

Comment: I saw this, but I didn't use the `myView.watsLayer = YES`! +1 for that.